# get email id of that particular user when i selected that user name from drop down

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement is when I select the name from the the drop down automatically the email id will appear below the name.

```
//Here I am getting all the user
 public List<SelectOption> UserList
{
    get
    {
        UserTemp = [Select u.LastName, u.Id, u.FirstName From User u ];            
        UserList = new List<SelectOption>();           
        for(User temp : UserTemp)
        {
            UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.FirstName+' '+temp.LastName));               
        }
        return UserList;
    }
    set;
}

// Below is my VF code for user drop down

<apex:selectList size="1">
 Full Name: 
<apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:selectList size="1">
```

Here what I am trying to get the email and need to set to the VF page

```
public User user { get; set; }
public String UserId { get; set; }

public PageReference loadDetails(){
     user = [Select u.email From User u Where u.Id = :UserId ];
return user;
}
```

But not getting idea how to pass the UserId from VF page to get the Email Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to capture the selected value in `UserId` variable and then use `actionSupport` to rerender the component you wish to render again.

Your `selectList` should be

```
<apex:selectList value="{!UserId}" size="1">
 Full Name: 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}"></apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="userEmail" action="{!loadDetails}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:outputText id="userEmail" value={!user.Email}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual force Page : when we select any user , we store that user id into the
**selectedUser** , and then same will do query on users for getting the user email, and just reRender pageblock when we select anyone from the list.

```
<apex:page controller="userListController">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pageblk">
        <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedUser}">  
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!loademail}" reRender="pageblk"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}"/>
                <!--apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}" onchange=""></apex:selectOptions-->
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>{!userDetails.email}</apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```
 public class userListController {
    public User userDetails { get; set; }
    public String UserId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> UserList {get;set;}
     public Id selectedUser {get; set;}

       public userListController(){
            List<User> usr = new List<User>();
            userDetails = new User();
                usr = [Select LastName,Id,FirstName From User ];            
                UserList = new List<SelectOption>();           
                    for(User temp : usr)
                    {
                        UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.FirstName+' '+temp.LastName));               
                    }
        }
        public void loademail(){
            System.debug('---selectedUser'+selectedUser);

         userDetails = [Select id,email From User Where Id = :selectedUser ];

        }
    }
```